# How to measure retention statistics?

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data-analysis

I have a dataset with the ID, name, joining date, leaving date as features. I was asked to measure employee retention and health of it. What can I derive from these?

What are some latest trends and examples which I can find relating these?

Thanks.

I know this is a discussion, but given that I couldn't find this on google search, it would be helpful for someone.

Comment: Maybe you could read some general review papers on this topic, e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40547-017-0080-0

Comment: Can you give us some instances of your data please.

Answer (score 1):

ID and name are probably not predictive of retention.

With joining and leaving date, you can model the distribution of time at the organization.

Unless you have other features, you will not be create a useful model.